# Current.user is set to nil after a post request in mini test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, minitest

I'm using Current Attributes:
https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/CurrentAttributes.html

```
class Current < ActiveSupport::CurrentAttributes
  attribute :account, :user
  attribute :request_id, :user_agent, :ip_address

  resets { Time.zone = nil }

  def user=(user)
    super
    self.account = user.account
    Time.zone    = user.time_zone
  end
end
```

Using Minitest, when I make a post request, `Current` is set to an `empty hash`.  Get requests are ok.  I found that this is supposed to happen with background jobs: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/36298 - and the hack on the last post works but I would like to find out if there are any other options.

But can't figure out why it's happening with post requests.

Example test:

```
  test "create new contact" do
    Current.user = users(:standard_user)

    new_contact_params = {contact: {first_name: "first name", last_name: "last name"}}
    post contacts_path, params: new_contact_params
    
    Current.user # Current user is nil here so I can't do something like Current.user.contacts.any?

    assert_response :success
  end
```

Comment: Can you add your Minitest example which results in Current being set to nil?

Comment: Added test  @Stefan

Comment: The whole point of CurrentAttributes is that it provides a thread local set of attributes and your tests and the web requests are running in different threads. While you could stub the singleton from your tests I don't think this is a very good use of it. Doing `Time.zone    = user.time_zone` is also not thread safe. You instead should use `Time.use_zone`.

Comment: @max if tests and web requests are in different threads, then how is a web request setting Current.user which is in my test to nil?  `Time.zone  = user.time_zone` is from the documentation, and Current attributes are thread safe from what I understand: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/CurrentAttributes.html

Answer (score 0):

The reason why Current.user is nil in your test is because Minitest runs in a separate thread from the main application thread. When you make a post request, the request is handled by the main application thread, but the CurrentAttributes object is not available in the separate thread.

To fix this, you can use the `around` hook in Minitest to run the request in the main application thread. Here is an example:

```
class CreateContactTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test "create new contact" do
    Current.user = users(:standard_user)

    around do |example|
      in_main_thread do
        example.run
      end
    end

    new_contact_params = {contact: {first_name: "first name", last_name: "last name"}}
    post contacts_path, params: new_contact_params

    assert_response :success
    assert Current.user.contacts.any?
  end
end
```

Comment: Current.user works most of the time in my tests, its just after a post, put etc request that it's getting reset to nil.  From my research this is expected behaviour.  The only issue with the above workaround is `around` is not in standard minitest, and the in_main_thread block is more invasive than the current fix which is re-assigning Current.user to standard user.